# Does this power series have a formula?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, power-series

How can I express $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x^{n^2}$ differently ? I'm working on a Number Theory problem and the solution is the coefficient of a power series related to the one above.

Comment: Can you give a little more context?  You may be falling victim to the [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)

Comment: $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k x^k$, where $a_k=1$ if $k=n^2$ for some $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $k=0$ if $k\neq n^2$ for any $n\in\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: @NickPeterson I was able to solve the other problem differently (it asked to show that there is only a finite number of positive integers that cannot be written as a sum of pairwise distinct perfect squares) but I was just curious to whether or not this power series have a different representation.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_triple_product  and $$ r_2(n)=\left|\{(a,b)\in\mathbb{Z}^2:a^2+b^2=n\}\right|=4\left(\chi_4 * 1\right)(n) $$ where $\chi_4$ is the non-principal Dirichlet's character $\pmod{4}$ and $*$ is the Dirichlet convolution.